# Doubly linked list segmentation fault C

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to create a doubly linked list in C using the following structs. But I get segmentation fault sometimes, but other times the code is working fine.

Here is my code.

```
typedef struct PageFrame
{
    int frameNumber;
    char *data;
    struct PageFrame *next;
    struct PageFrame *prev;
} PageFrame;


// Buffer pool manager stores the data of a single buffer pool
// TODO: Figure out what more data is required here
typedef struct PageFrame_Manager
{
    PageFrame *head;
    PageFrame *tail;
} PageFrame_Manager;

bool createPageFrames(const int numPages, PageFrame_Manager *pf_mgr)
{
    int i = 0;
    do
    {
        PageFrame *pf = (PageFrame *)malloc(sizeof(PageFrame));
        pf->frameNumber = i;
        pf->data = calloc(4096, sizeof(char *));

        // head of page frame linked list
        if (pf_mgr->head == NULL)
        {
            pf_mgr->head = pf;
            pf_mgr->tail = pf;
            pf_mgr->start = pf;
            pf->next = NULL;
            pf->prev = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            pf_mgr->tail->next = pf;
            pf->prev = pf_mgr->tail;
            pf_mgr->tail = pf;
            pf->next = NULL;
        }
        i++;
    } while (i < numPages);
    pf_mgr->tail->next = pf_mgr->head;
    pf_mgr->head->prev = pf_mgr->tail;
    return 1;
}
```

I am not able to figure out where am I getting the segmentation fault. Can anyone please help?

Below is the error when I ran the program using lldb.

```
Process 18482 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
    frame #0: 0x00000001000028fb assign2_1`createPageFrames + 187
assign2_1`createPageFrames:
->  0x1000028fb <+187>: movq   %rax, 0x20(%rcx)
    0x1000028ff <+191>: movq   -0x20(%rbp), %rax
    0x100002903 <+195>: movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rcx
    0x100002907 <+199>: movq   %rax, 0x18(%rcx)
Target 0: (assign2_1) stopped.
```

Comment: Questions requesting debugging help must provide a [complete minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That is, anyone should be able to take your code exactly as shown and run it to reproduce the problem.

Comment: We need all, and only, the code needed to reproduce the problem. If you can't replicate the problem without some piece of code, that piece of code might be the problem.

Comment: Also, learn to debug effectively. It seems you are using a debugger which is a good first step. Now continue debugging with it - for example, use it to show the exact line of C code that triggers the seg fault. And look at the pointer values at that point to see if any of them are NULL or invalid.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Please don't tag C code as C++.

Comment: Shouldn't `calloc(4096, sizeof(char *))` be `calloc(4096, sizeof(char))`? Any way, you should provide the code to reproduce the issue. The code you provided lacks the initialisation of `pf_mgr` and the actual call to the function that would trigger the exception.